# Clojure/Solr: Exception when trying to use org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer from Clojure

Tags: solr, clojure

I am trying to upgrade the clojure-solr library to 1.3 (I did not write it originally, this is a fork) and I am encountering a problem when interacting to apache-solr-3.5.0.  Here is the updated library on github:

https://github.com/antler/clojure-solr

It is a very simple one file project that basically just imports the barebones java classes.  I am trying to connect to the solr example app that comes bundled with the solr 3.5.0 release (this is one mirror):

http://www.fightrice.com/mirrors/apache//lucene/solr/3.5.0/

In this release I cd into example/ and run

```
java -jar start.jar
```

This seems to work fine.  Then, from the repl in the clojure-solr project (after running lein deps):

```
(use 'clojure-solr)

(with-connection (connect "http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr") 
  (add-document! {"id" "testdoc", "name" "A Test Document"})
  (add-documents! [{"id" "testdoc.2", "name" "Another test"}
                   {"id" "testdoc.3", "name" "a final test"}])
  (commit!)
  (search "test")
  (search "test" :rows 2))
```

This is from the example given in the library originally.  The call to connect runs fine, but fails on add with the following exception:

```
IllegalArgumentException No matching field found: add 
  for class org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer
```

I checked in the solr docs and the add method is definitely there:

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CommonsHttpSolrServer.html

What am I missing here?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clojure-solr turns the vector of documents into an array in `add-documents!`. However there is no `.add` method of `CommonsHttpSolrServer` for an array.

Changing clojure-solr to pass on a vector might fix the issue since a vector implements `java.util.List` - and thusly `java.util.Collection`. Not tested. Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

How about using something like:

```
(add-documents! (list {"id" "testdoc.2", "name" "Another test"}
                   {"id" "testdoc.3", "name" "a final test"}))
```

OR

```
(add-documents! '({"id" "testdoc.2", "name" "Another test"}
                   {"id" "testdoc.3", "name" "a final test"}))
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019 [corona clojure solr wrapper](https://github.com/Stylitics/corona) is the way to go.

```
(corona.index/add! client-config [{"id" "testdoc.2", "name" "Another test"}
                                  {"id" "testdoc.3", "name" "a final test"}])
```

Is doesn't rely on Solrj, but rather directly on REST API.

Example usage here: https://github.com/Stylitics/corona-demo